# post created but no permalink

Tags: php, theme-development

i m trying to create a post in the custom postype via frontend , the post is created successfully too. but the cutom permalink is blank unless i go into the dashboard andclick on update

```
 $todaydate = new DateTime();
 $todaydate =$todaydate->format('Y-m-d H-i-s');
 $bookid="harrypotter";
 $mypost= array('post_type'=>'books',
                    'post_title'=>$bookid,
        'post_author'=>'1',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'post_date'=>$todaydate);

$wpdb->insert('wp_posts',$mypost); 
$bookid=$wpdb->insert_id;
```

when i go into the posttype books i find the post created but the permalink is `http://localhost/mysite/newbooks//` instead of `http://localhost/mysite/newbooks/harrypotter/`

so how do i get it to update the permalink of post too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't insert into the database directly. Use the proper functions so that the posts are properly created before being inserted into the database.

In your case the proper function is `wp_insert_post()`:

```
wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_type'   => 'books',
    'post_title'  => 'harrypotter',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
) );
```

The date field doesn't need to be set manually if you want the current time.